# CWE-201: Information Exposure Through Sent Data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, veracode

Good Day Everyone

I have a Veracode Greenlight extension on my VS 2017, I got this flaw below.

**CWE-201: Information Exposure Through Sent Data**

*Sensitive information may be exposed as a result of outbound network connections made by the application. This can manifest in a couple of different ways.
In C/C++ applications, sometimes the developer fails to zero out a buffer before populating it with data. This can cause information leakage if, for example, the buffer contains a data structure for which only certain fields were populated. The uninitialized fields would contain whatever data is present at that memory location. Sensitive information from previously allocated variables could then be leaked when the buffer is sent over the network.
Mobile applications may also transmit sensitive information such as email or SMS messages, address book entries, GPS location data, and anything else that can be accessed by the mobile API. This behavior is common in mobile spyware applications designed to exfiltrate data to a listening post or other data collection point. This flaw is categorized as low severity because it only impacts confidentiality, not integrity or availability. However, in the context of a mobile application, the significance of an information leak may be much greater, especially if misaligned with user expectations or data privacy policies.*

This flaws show on this code

```
        Using objSMTPClient = New SmtpClient

            With objSMTPClient
                .EnableSsl = False
                .DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.PickupDirectoryFromIis
                .Send(objMail)
                .Dispose()
            End With

        End Using
```

the **.Send(objMail)** is the one that has the flaws, I have tried everything to fix this issue, but none of it has work and still a findings, does everyone knows how to fix it?

Thanks you

Comment: I doubt that there's anything you can do.  It's probably just designed to flag calls to `SmptClient.Send` no matter what.  The only thing I can imagine that might help is if you were to explicitly set every property of the `MailMessage` prior to calling `Send`.

Comment: By the way, your `Dispose` call is pointless.  The reason for the `Using` block is dispose the object at the end of the block.

Comment: Maybe enabling SSL? Or using another SMTP client, as also [recommended in the Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=netframework-4.8#remarks). Or configuring the *validator*, if there's a way to specify that an out-bound communication doesn't necessarily compromise confidentiality.

Answer (score 0):

I have a HTML Body. I tried to test if i change it on a non HTML body, and the **Information Exposure Through Sent Data** is gone, but the problem is I need the HTML Body to format my email, check my code below

```
            Using strREader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/HTML/EmailBody.html"))

            readFile = strREader.ReadToEnd


            Dim myString As String = ""

            myString = readFile
            myString = myString.Replace("EmailMessage", GetMessage)
            myString = myString.Replace("GetLink", GetURL)
            myString = myString.Replace("CreatedBy", GetUserFullName)
            myString = myString.Replace("DateCreated", Date.Now)


            Using objSMPTClient As SmtpClient = New SmtpClient

                objMailMsg.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8
                objMailMsg.Subject = "My Email Test - " & GetSubject
                objMailMsg.Body = myString.ToString
                objMailMsg.Priority = MailPriority.High
                objMailMsg.IsBodyHtml = True

                objSMPTClient.EnableSsl = False
                objSMPTClient.Send(objMailMsg)

            End Using

        End Using
```